# how to access pk_set when m2m_changed call with action "pre_clear"?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I want to use `m2m_changed` signal when a realtion in ManyToMany field removed. I write this code in `models.py`:

```
class Unit(Model):
    # ....

class Package(Model):
    # ...
    Lesson = ManyToManyField(Unit, blank=True)

def toppings_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("pk_set") and kwargs.get("action") == "pre_clear":
        # get id of lesson to delete and do something with it
m2m_changed.connect(toppings_changed, sender=Packages.Lesson.through)
```

I want to do something when removing a `Lesson`  relation in `Package` Model. but when I remove a relation `pre_clear` will call and I can't access to `pk_set` (it is None). Is there a way to access `Unit` id when remove a relation in Lesson Model.

Answer (score 0):

1. *First:* `m2m_changed` is called when **any** of the two sides of a *many-to-many* relation changes. i.e. `some_unit.package_set.clear()` and `some_package.Lesson.clear()` **both** can trigger the registered signal.
2. *Second*: In the `pre_clear` state, all relations still exist (since it's actually **pre**-clear). So you can see what's gonna be removed like this:

```py
def toppings_changed(sender, reverse, action, **kwargs):
    if action == "pre_clear":
        if reverse:
            # sender is of type Unit
            # i.e. current signal is raised by: some_unit.package_set.clear()
            packages_to_be_removed = sender.package_set.all()
        else:
            # sender is of type Package
            # i.e. current signal is raised by: some_package.Lesson.clear()
            lessons_to_be_removed = sender.Lesson.all()
```

Comment: I was for a while confused with upper-case `Lesson`. It is indeed a field on `Package` class.

Comment: @dhill You're right. It's not an appropriate naming. But I've just tried to stay consistent with the questioned example.

Answer (score -1):

Per the Django 1.8 docs.:

> pk_set ...
> For the pre_clear and post_clear actions, this is None.
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

So you'll have to generate it by other means like @Emran BatmanGhelich suggested